# Retrieve single record to model with EF Linq, does it need to loop to populate?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Most of the time I retrieve multiple records so I would end up doing this

```
var rpmuser = new List<rpm_scrty_rpm_usr>();
```

1. I have my List collection of properties from poco
2. So I typically use `select new`  in my `Linq` statement
3. Then I use a `foreach` and loop over the records in which the List would get   model.Add(new instance in each loop)

**However** ,  do I really need to be doing all this looping to populate?

**Bigger question**  when i have a **single record** should I be needing to even do a **loop** at all?

```
public bool UpdateAllUsers(string user, string hash, string salt)
{
    bool status = false;

    var rpmuser = new rpm_scrty_rpm_usr();

    var query = (from t in db.rpm_usr
                    .Where(z => z.usr_id == "MillXZ")
                 select new
                 {
                     t.usr_id,
                     t.usr_lnm,
                     t.usr_pwd,
                     t.usr_fnm,
                     t.salt,
                     t.inact_ind,
                     t.lst_accs_dtm,
                     t.lst_pwd_chg_dtm,
                     t.tel,
                     t.wwid,
                     t.email_id,
                     t.dflt_ste_id,
                     t.apprvr_wwid,
                     t.chg_dtm,
                     t.chg_usr_id,
                     t.cre_dtm,
                     t.cre_usr_id,
                 });

    foreach(var s in query)
    {
        rpmuser.wwid = s.wwid;
        rpmuser.usr_pwd = s.usr_pwd;
        rpmuser.usr_lnm = s.usr_lnm;
        rpmuser.usr_id = s.usr_id;
        rpmuser.usr_fnm = s.usr_fnm;
        rpmuser.tel = s.tel;
        rpmuser.salt = s.salt;
        rpmuser.lst_pwd_chg_dtm = rpmuser.lst_pwd_chg_dtm;
        rpmuser.lst_accs_dtm = s.lst_accs_dtm;
        rpmuser.inact_ind = s.inact_ind;
        rpmuser.email_id = s.email_id;
        rpmuser.apprvr_wwid = s.apprvr_wwid;
        rpmuser.chg_dtm = s.chg_dtm;
        rpmuser.chg_usr_id = s.chg_usr_id;
        rpmuser.cre_usr_id = s.cre_usr_id;
        rpmuser.dflt_ste_id = s.dflt_ste_id;
        rpmuser.cre_dtm = s.cre_dtm;
    }

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;            

    try
    {
        rpmuser = db.rpm_usr.Find(rpmuser.usr_id);
        rpmuser.usr_pwd = hash;
        rpmuser.salt = salt;

        db.SaveChanges();
        status = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Of what type is stuff you are returning from your db?

Comment: ie is it of type rpm_scrty_rpm_usr

Comment: So I'm getting  first and last names, salt, email , hash, various dates and several digit numbers etc.

Comment: No I mean what type does db.rpm_usr return

Comment: public DbSet<rpm_scrty_rpm_usr> rpm_usr { get; set; }    which is just then that class of properties  rpm_scrty_rpm_usr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you want. Your method says Update All, but only seems to be attempting to update one record. So why don't you just do this?

```
        try
        {
            var rpmuser = db.rpm_usr.Single(z => z.usr_id == "MillXZ");
            rpmuser.usr_pwd = hash;
            rpmuser.salt = salt;

            db.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status = false;
        }
```

You have a lot of redundant declarations unless I am missing something. In the case of the list you will do something like this:

```
        var query  = db.rpm_usr.Where(z => z.usr_id == "...some string...");
        foreach(var item in query)
        {
            rpmuser.usr_pwd = ...some value...;
            rpmuser.salt = ...some value...;
        }   
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Ok, I am looking    Yes I do need to clean up the code ,    and yes the reason for the method called `UpdateAllUsers` is the intention of being able to loop through the users and then update each one

Comment: I am thinking that I will just have a loop that actually calls `UpdateAllUsers` passing in the parameters like user , hash, salt   and then I need to update their information.   I was thinking that I need to do a Find(user)  in order to update  , right?

Comment: You could do a Find... or you can do a Single like I did in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't stress this enough, **Murdock's answer is absolutely the right way to fix the code you've shown. You are writing way too much code for what you're trying to accomplish.**

However, to answer your question about whether you need to loop **in other situations**, you can get away from having to loop by doing the projection into a new type as part of your LINQ-to-Entities query. The looping still happens, you just don't see it.

```
var query = db.rpm_usr
    .Where(z => z.usr_id == "MillXZ")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(z => new rpm_scrty_rpm_usr()
        {
            usr_id = z.usr_id,
            usr_lnm = z.usr_lnm,
            // etc...
        });
```

You would then finish the query off with a `.Single()`, `.SingleOrDefault()`, or `.ToList()` depending on whether you expected exactly one, one or zero, or a list. For example, in this case if you might find one or zero users with the name "MillXZ" you would write the following.

```
var query = db.rpm_usr
    .Where(z => z.usr_id == "MillXZ")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(z => new rpm_scrty_rpm_usr()
        {
            usr_id = z.usr_id,
            usr_lnm = z.usr_lnm,
            // etc...
        })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ok,  so say I'm looping over users outside of the method i showed.  ,  so then a call is repeatedly for each user is sending a call to `UpdateAllUsers` in which it passes in the user, hash, salt  values in which I would do a Find()  in order to do an Update...   and then SaveChanges()

Comment: I'm realizing that I have added a question on top of the original question,   let me sort this out a bit